# unable to see the image in the frontend, joomla website

Tags: html, css, joomla, web, joomla3.0

My website is running on joomla 3.0 and I have created a customHTML module type on the about us page of the website `www.earthandwaterpictures.com`. My problem is updating the text of this particular module is getting reflected on the frontend, but when i'm trying to insert an image, left aligned with the text, everything but the image is getting displayed properly. In short, I'm able to make changes to the text, but not the the image.

Here is the link to the about us page http://earthandwaterpictures.com/index.php/about-us.
I have tried clearing the cache of the browser and also from the joomla system menu.
If you right click and inspect element on the browser itself, you'll see the  tag without any syntax error or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture has `display: none`.

[image]

You should probably get rid of the `fav-breadcrumbs` id on the container element:
[image]

Comment: oh i didn't know how to do that..but i just did.